# How do I perform COUNT( ) while using LEFT JOIN (Leetcode problem 1158 Market Analysis)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_id AS buyer_id, join_date, 
    CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2019 THEN COUNT(order_date)
    ELSE 0
    END AS orders_in_2019
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN Orders O ON U.user_id = O.buyer_id
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I am facing problem with orders_in_2019 column for user_id no. 1. It's count should be 1 as per the solution but i am getting the output as 0. I have seen some solutions where adding
another condition like `AND YEAR(order_date) = 2019` while joining solves the problem but why it is so? Please help me with this doubt.

Thanks

Link to the problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/market-analysis-i/

Comment: I wonder why you need to do ```CASE```, its a simple count, if you refer [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXocP23Zi4zyQbpy56dYXB/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the placement of the aggregate COUNT function in a scalar context, inside the CASE expression.

The value of the aggregate will not be available until after the GROUP BY operation, and the query is going to be looking at a value of `order_date` column from just *one* of the joined rows. Some of those may be 2019 dates, and some may not.  That's why adding a condition to the JOIN condition, so only 2019 order dates are returned seems to work.

---

For the **Conditional Aggregation** pattern, do the aggregation *outside* of the conditional test.

We want a conditional test on each individual row, something like this

```
CASE WHEN  some_condition_is_true  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

if the condition is true, return 1 else return 0. First write the query without the aggregate, to see what is being returned,

```
SELECT u.user_id AS buyer_id
     , u.join_date
     , o.order_date
     , YEAR(o.order_date)
     , CASE WHEN YEAR(o.order_date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS order_in_2019
     , CASE WHEN YEAR(o.order_date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS order_in_2020
  FROM `Users` u
  LEFT
  JOIN `Orders` o
    ON u.user_id = o.buyer_id
 ORDER
    BY u.user_id
     , u.join_date
     , o.order_date
```

---

The CASE expressions are going to return either a 0 or 1 for each row returned, which is what we want.

We can now tweak that query to add a `GROUP BY` clause to collapse the rows, and we can wrap the CASE expressions in SUM aggregate to add up the 1s and 0s to get a count.

Conditional aggregation makes sense when we are wanting to return multiple counts, if we filter out all rows from Orders that arent in 2019 (adding a condition to the JOIN),  then we cant get counts for other years,

Demonstration of conditional aggregation pattern

```
SELECT u.user_id AS buyer_id
     , u.join_date
     , SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(o.order_date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS orders_in_2019
     , SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(o.order_date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS orders_in_2020
  FROM `Users` u
  LEFT
  JOIN `Orders` o
    ON u.user_id = o.buyer_id
 GROUP
    BY u.user_id
 ORDER
    BY u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT is an aggregate function, and you are using it incorrectly.
Change your query a little to:

```
SELECT user_id AS buyer_id, join_date, 
SUM(CASE 
WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2019 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS orders_in_2019
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN Orders O ON U.user_id = O.buyer_id
GROUP BY user_id;
```